# iPhone app crash without any log

Tags: iphone, memory, crash

My application is crashing after play with it 10 min.

And in console nothing is show about this crash and no waring, no logs.

And I am not getting any memory warning.

Please help me.

Comment: use breck Point to find Out where is a bug for crashing your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Adding breakpoints in the code to check the point where application is crashing..

Comment: I tried it but it remove all breakpoint and clean console before crash.

Answer (score 2):

See Next to stop button your project name will be there click there and go to edit `Scheme -> Argument -> Environment Variables ->` click on `+` button and write `NSZombieEnabled` and then value `YES`.

It will tell that where exactly your app is crashing.

Comment: Done But still not getting any notification. I think this is Code4.5 bug

Comment: now add the breakpoints and debug your code then you will come to know the line that where it is crasing...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your `Run Static Analyzer` to YES then `shift+Command+B`. See if you have potential Memory Leaks. Or try running you code with Intruments.

or try this:

`Edit Scheme`
[image]

then add the `NSZombieEnabled` like the image below.
[image]

Comment: Done But still not getting any notification. I think this is Code4.5 bug